# Best way to conditionally override an item value in an Ansible loop

Tags: loops, ansible

I'm attempting to adapt an existing play that was built for automating account creation and deletion in a small environment without centralized authentication. Since then the scope has expanded and we've added bastion servers where it's not appropriate for all accounts to be created.

Because user IDs are hard coded (not desirable - I know) I'd like to avoid having a separate play for the bastions as that means keeping track of UIDs in two places. My workaround was to add an onbastion boolean to each row, then use that in create-account.yml to flip the state to absent if applicable.  I originally tried changing the value of item.state directly but ran into syntax errors that I couldn't figure out.  So I added a set_fact task to set the value of a new variable conditionally, but the playbook now fails with a message that *"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'desired_item_state' is undefined"*.

What am I missing, and is there a better way to tackle this?  Thanks in advance!

## Relevant Snippets

### project/roles/create-accounts/default/main.yml

```
users:
  - { name: "user_1",         id: 15001, state: "present", groups: ["project"], onbastion: true }
  - { name: "user_2",         id: 15002, state: "present", groups: ["project"], onbastion: true }
  - { name: "fired_user_3",   id: 15003, state: "absent",  groups: [],          onbastion: false}
  - { name: "retired_user_4", id: 15004, state: "absent",  groups: [],          onbastion: false}
  - { name: "osr1",           id: 15009, state: "present", groups: ["project"], onbastion: false }
  - { name: "osr2",           id: 15010, state: "present", groups: ["project"], onbastion: false }
  - { name: "osr3",           id: 15011, state: "present", groups: ["project"], onbastion: false }
  - { name: "project_svc",    id: 15018, state: "present", groups: ["project"], onbastion: false }
  - { name: "jenkins",        id: 15019, state: "present", groups: ["project"], onbastion: false }
```

### project/roles/create-accounts/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Set up user accounts
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: create-account.yml
  loop: "{{ users }}"
```

### project/roles/create-accounts/tasks/create-account.yml

```
---

- name: Update item state if on bastion
  set_fact:
    desired_item_state: "{{ 'absent' if ('bastion' in group_names and item.onbastion == false) else item.state }}"

- name: Create/update {{ item.name }} user ID
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: "{{ desired_item_state }}"
    uid: "{{ item.id }}"
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    append: yes
    update_password: on_create
    password: "!"

- name: Create/update {{ item.name }} group ID
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.group:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: "{{ desired_item_state }}"
    gid: "{{ item.id }}"

- name: Update ownership of /home/{{ item.name }}
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /home/{{ item.name }}
    state: directory
    recurse: yes
    owner: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: "{{ item.name }}"
  when: desired_item_state == 'present'
```

## Output

```
TASK [create-accounts : Create/update osr1 user ID] ***********************
fatal: [project-subsystem-bastion2]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'desired_item_state' is undefined

    The error appears to be in '/project/ansible-e86f3754/plays/roles/create-accounts/tasks/create-account.yml': line 13, column 3, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

    The offending line appears to be:

    - name: Create/update {{ item.name }} user ID
      ^ here
    We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
    missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
    start a value. For instance:

        with_items:
          - {{ foo }}

    Should be written as:

        with_items:
          - "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with the code that you provided, nor is it generally possible for a variable which is set using `set_fact` to be undefined in the very next task. Either something that you didn't include in your question is resulting in your set_fact task being skipped, or you are in some other way running code that differs from what you provided here.

Comment: "something that you didn't include in your question is resulting in your set_fact task being skipped" - how right you are.  I removed tags before posting the code to simplify things and just noticed that the set_fact task was tagged "create-accounts" and I ran ansible-playbook with "--tags create_accounts".  Hyphen instead of underscore.  I'm kicking myself for leaving that out now, and I appreciate your help in narrowing down the root cause!

Answer (score 0):

See comments.  flowerysong was unable to reproduce my issue, and the only thing I'd left out were tags on the tasks.  Lesson learned: sanitize code before posting but don't leave anything out.